# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" When Importing React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error

I'm starting to learn react from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLX62G4lc44
so I did first 2 chapters and all good, then a week later I run the same code exactly and started to get this error:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**
I tried every thing on the web, best thing I got is put type="module" or type="text"
the error gone but nothing shows up at the page!
and got this new error:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'**
can somebody please help, I'm starting to give up please help here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello React</h1>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

JS:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
function MyApp(){
    return(
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp/>,document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: How did you set up your toolchain? How are you transpiling the JSX syntax?

Comment: You need a compiler to build that file into something that the browser can use. The browser doesn’t know where to import React from.

Comment: Frankly, find a better tutorial. Based on your understand, the one you are using is leaving out a lot of essentials. The one on the React website is a good starting point.

Comment: I just downloaded Nodejs, react and started coding like the tutorial @Bergi

Comment: Thank you @Quentin I'll check it out..

Comment: @AliAlomar The I doubt it ever worked

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

To solve this you need to add to the HTML script tag `type="text/babel"`
like so: `<script src="path/to/script" type="text/babel"></script>`

And to solve the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" I did a quick Google search and found this:

> https://nkaushik.com/javascript/solved-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-module/

In short: In your package.json file, simply add “type”:“module”

If you don't have a package.json here are the docs on how to make one:

> https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file

Write in console `npm install react-scripts`
than make sure you're package.json file have this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Don't forget to add a comma, after that in console write `npm start`

Comment: Thanks a lot, both error gone but still the page is blank, react code didn't work I mean the <ul> didn't get injected in the root tag.

Comment: I don't have a package.json, also how come in all the tutorials no one do this stuff, they just type and all work perfectly, I'm doing the same thing same code!!.

Comment: i edited my answer i hope it will help u,